# Custom String Formatting, number to time

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, string-formatting, number-formatting

I want to convert a number to a time, like

```
10  ->  00:10  
55  ->  00:55  
75  ->  01:15  
90  ->  01:30  
705 ->  11:45
```

and so on. I know I can write a method and do this convertion, but I need it for a `DataGridView` so I'd better use a string `Format`.

As far as I know there is not such a thing implemented. How I can implement this format so that I can set it on the Grid's `DefaultCellStyle.Format`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `TimeSpan` from the minutes first:

```
TimeSpan minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(705);
```

Then use `DateTime.Add`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Add( minutes );
```

Now you can use `DateTime.ToString`:

```
string text = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

You could also use [`TimeSpan.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)(although `DateTime.ToString` is more readable):

```
text = minutes.ToString(@"hh\:mm")
```

You can use the DataGridViews `CellFormatting` event.

[How to: Customize Data Formatting in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h.aspx?ppud=4)

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your detailed answer. So I cannot do it as a simple format, right? I'm asking that because DataGridView gets a Format as a string and this great code is not translatable to a string, am I right?

Comment: Yes, not to my knowledge.